# Missing dependencies when building @com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_lite

Tags: macos, protocol-buffers, bazel

When trying to build `:protoc` on OS X from https://github.com/google/protobuf/ (the 3.4.1 release) I get the following:

````
$ bazel build @com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_lite

ERROR: <...>/external/com_google_protobuf/BUILD:93:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_lite':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc':
  '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stddef.h'
  '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/__stddef_max_align_t.h'
  '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stdint.h'
  '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/stdarg.h'
  '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include/limits.h'.
```
````

but, when building the target not as an external repo, it succeeds.

```
$ cd <...>/external/com_google_protobuf/
$ bazel build :protobuf_lite
```

The listed headers are system headers, so I'm missing something very obvious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2852#issuecomment-295747929 :

Setting `BAZEL_SH=/bin/bash` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I got this same error today after upgrading MacOS command line tools.

What worked for me was `bazel clean --expunge`.  Without --expunge it didn't fix the issue.